# Can you solve this Rubik's cube from inside of it?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual, story, rubiks-cube

You have woken up to find yourself trapped in what appears to be a giant Rubik's cube. A Rubik's Cage I suppose. Bewildered, you take a look around ([better video on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qrSB.jpg) or just click the photo).

[image]

Each of the individual cube faces seems to have a letter transcribed onto it from outside, although it is difficult to read from inside.

Glancing down, you find a tablet and a diagram by your feet:

[image] [image]

It would seem you need to enter a single 9 letter word into the tablet to escape. Who knows what will happen if you get it wrong... Maybe solving the cube will help reveal the answer?

Here's a better look at the sides of your cage (click for higher resolution):

(For those who struggle to see the colours, click edit to see the layout of each face)

---

Walls:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Ceiling/Floor respectively:

[image] [image]

---

### Can you solve this Rubik's Cube from inside of it and find the 9 letter word to escape?

Don't get it wrong, there's only one attempt remaining!

Comment: The GIF is sadly rather lower quality due to the 2 MiB cap on media here. [Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/uEFg3Ie) is a better video on imgur of you looking around the cage.

Comment: Is the tablet looking for a single English word?

Comment: @jpthesolver2 correct - one 9 letter word

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The password is

> ROTATIONS.

First, solve the Rubik's Cube.

> Every cubelet in a Rubik's cube contains a unique combination of either 2 or 3 different colored stickers. Because of this, for each cubelet, we can simply look for the correct spot on the diagram. Actually solving the cube is unnecessary (although for what it's worth, `L F' R2 U2 F2 U' B2 R2 D L B' R2 U2 L2 B2 D F2 L2 R2 U F2` will solve it).
>
>   Here is the completed diagram:
>
>   [image]

Now to find the password.

> Each face contains a message encoded with a Viginere cipher. The key for each cipher is the last 5 letters of the *ciphertext* of the previous face. The order of the faces is White, Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Orange, hinted by the numbers on each face and the letters `RGBYO` on the white face.
>
>  Here are the faces and the messages they encode:
>
> ```
>  White:  KEY1RGBYO
>  Red:    BKZ2PCCRT [RGBYO] -> KEY2ROLLS
>  Green:  ZGA3DHKGU [PCCRT] -> KEY3MOVES
>  Blue:   NLI4ZOUUC [DHKGU] -> KEY4TURNS
>  Yellow: JSS5MRHBM [ZOUUC] -> KEY5SPINS
>  Orange: DFABFUFUT [MRHBM] -> ROTATIONS
> ```
>
> The last message in the chain is `ROTATIONS`, which is the password.

Comment: i hate you, i just solved the cube after half an hour and saw your answer

Comment: Correct! Congratulations and unlucky @enigmaticcard :P This was a slightly different puzzle, hopefully it was still enjoyable!